# SwiftUI ForEach Binding compile time error looks like not for-each

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm starting with SwiftUI and following WWDC videos I'm starting with `@State` and `@Binding` between two views. I got a display right, but don't get how to make back-forth read-write what was not include in WWDC videos.

I have model classes:

```swift
class Manufacturer {
    let name: String
    var models: [Model] = []
    
    init(name: String, models: [Model]) {
        self.name = name
        self.models = models
    }
}

class Model: Identifiable {
    var name: String = ""
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

Then I have a drawing code to display that work as expected:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(manufacturer.models) { model in
            Text(model.name).padding()
        }
    }.padding()
}
```

and I see this:
[Canvas preview picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ4XB.png)

But now I want to modify my code to allows editing this models displayed and save it to my model `@Binding` so I've change view to:

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(self.$manufacturer.models) { item in
            Text(item.name)
        }
    }.padding()
}
```

But getting and error in `ForEach` line:

> Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred

What ID parameter? I'm clueless here... I thought `Identifiable` acting as identifier here.

My question is then:
I have one view (ContentView) that "holds" my datasource as `@State` variable. Then I'm passing this as `@Binding` to my `ManufacturerView` want to edit this in `List` with `ForEach` fill but cannot get for each binding working - how can I do that?

Comment: this may be not directly related to the question, but are you intending to use the binding to each element of `manufacturer.models` array, in something like `TextField("update name", item.name)`?

Comment: yes! that's exactly what I'm trying to accomplish here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'm assuming you have something like:

```
@ObservedObject var manufacturer: Manufacturer
```

otherwise you wouldn't have `self.$manufacturer` to begin with (which also requires `Manufacturer` to conform to `ObservableObject`).

`self.$manufacturer.models` is a type of `Binding<[Model]>`, and as such it's not a `RandomAccessCollection`, like `self.manufacturer.models`, which is one of the overloads that `ForEach.init` accepts.

And if you use `ForEach(self.manufacturer.models) { item in ... }`, then `item` isn't going to be a binding, which is what you'd need for, say, a `TextField`.

A way around that is to iterate over indices, and then bind to `$manufacturer.models[index].name`:

```
ForEach(manufacturer.indices) { index in
   TextField("model name", self.$manufacturer.models[index].name)
}
```

In addition to that, I'd suggest you make `Model` (and possibly even `Manufacturer`) a value-type, since it appears to be just a storage of data:

```
struct Model: Identifiable {
  var id: UUID = .init()
  var name: String = ""
}
```

This isn't going to help with this problem, but it will eliminate possible issues with values not updating, since SwiftUI wouldn't detect a change.

Comment: Thank you! working and I get a concept now, really helpful!